# Магическое число

Tags: типы, visual-c++, delphi, числа

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо определить тип файла по его магическому числу. Сделать это не проблема, проблема в другом, где мне взять табличку/список, короче хоть какое - нибудь соотношение магического числа файла и его типа. Т.е. есть тип jpeg магическое число у данного типа JFIF, но есть же куча других форматов, мне хотя бы самый распространенные узнать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[File Signatures Table](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)